# Can anyone help me identify the model of this Viking mountain bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, full-suspension

I've had a look online and couldn't find anything on it. I couldn't figure out what model of Viking bike this is, wondering if anyone could help.

[image: Image of a full-suspension mountain bike pictured from the non-drive side leaning against a fence. The bike is silver with visible labels "Viking" on the down tube, "VK200 Dual" on the top tube and "6061" on the seat tube]

Comment: Well, the decals on the top tube state VK200 dual (suspension) and it is clearly alumium (there's also 6061 written on the seattube) I must admit that I didn't find anything under that name and useful pages like 99spokes.com also didn't list VK200 models. Can you get a few more photos uploaded, showing details about the drivetrain like shifters, rear wheel, derailleurs? If all else fails, we can at least approximately date the bike if components are still original...

Comment: so, this bike is listed on eBay, here's some of the other photos with it; https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/204545373752?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D777008%26algo%3DPERSONAL.TOPIC%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20230811123856%26meid%3D683cdf6d6a8445de828f5e599f9ed00e%26pid%3D101770%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26itm%3D204545373752%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D4375194%26algv%3DRecentlyViewedItemsV2%26brand%3DViking&_trksid=p4375194.c101770.m146925&_trkparms=parentrq%3Afb7b474118b0a8d34cb483a2ffffbf14%7Cpageci%3A9323397b-89e1-11ee-9481-4a038f79dab9%7Ciid%3A1%7Cvlpname%3Avlp_homepage

Comment: I think the [answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/91468/69562) below based on the auction is pretty comprehensive. The only missing information is the groupset but since the VK300 referred to in the MTB reviews post had Shimano's second-lowest Altus equipped, I'd also expect period-correct Shimano MTB components. Given the fact the the "reference" bike was sold for 50 pounds 15 years ago and the seller even claims that it needs service, I wouldn't spend too much. Looks like the cabling should be redone and that'll probably exceed the expected price. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is what it says it is:  A Viking (brand bought by Avocet, which is now [Insync](https://www.insyncb2b.co.uk/viking)) VK200, Dual suspension.  I found the [eBay auction](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/204545373752) your picture is sourced from, which gives us a bit higher-res view.

[This post on MTB Reviews](https://www.mtbr.com/threads/is-this-any-good.582176/) gives a rundown of the specs of a bike similar enough to this one to be within a few years:

> - **Dual Suspension** 17" **6061 Aluminium** mainframe with aluminium swing arm. Replaceable gear hanger. Profiled top and down tubes with headstock gusset. Kindshock 290 oil damped rear suspension unit with adjustable preload.
> - **Suntour XCT suspension forks** with adjustable preload and ISO disc brake mount. Shimano STI levers with powerful Tektro alloy Vee brakes. Frame Colour :Metallic Grape & Black.
> - Shimano Altus 24 speed indexed gears with Shimano STI button shifters, Shimano front & rear derailleurs. Shimano 12T-32T rear 8sp cassette. Truvativ X-Flow 24T 34T 44T chainset.
> - Ritchey Girder XC alloy rims with black spokes & black **Quando cassette hubs with quick release levers**. 26" X 2.1 Ritchey Z-Max blackwall tyres.
> - Alloy Aheadset Stem & alloy 560mm XC riser bars. **Truvativ X-Flow cranks** with cartridge bottom bracket system. Ritchey cartridge aheadset, **Ritchey Vector saddle**. Black alloy micro-adjust seatpost

I've bolded the items that match the auction image; the rest might match too, but it's impossible to tell.

The post notes that the bike in question was acquired used in 2008, and cost £50, so this bike is likely more than 15 years old.

There is very little information available online about Viking bikes between the 1970s when they were still based in Manchester and making lightweight road/racing bikes, and much more recently, so I haven't been able to dig up any other information.